# Traveling abroad with high end cryptography devices and software

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, electronic-items

In the next months I’m going to travel abroad with my laptop. I’ll visit most of the EU countries, Russia, China, Brazil, U.S. and Canada. I’m an EU citizen.

I was wondering if I could get in trouble for bringing abroad my laptop where I have some sensitive informations encrypted with 4096 bits keys. (File level encryption)

I also have disk level encryption with bitlocker on Windows 10 and sha256 with luks on the Linux /home partition.

I would like to know which is my right to refuse to unlock my laptop whether I’m intimated to do so by a customs officer. As far as I know as an EU citizen in the EU *I can refuse* to unlock my devices without violating any law.

Comment: Since you are looking for legal advice, wouldn't this be more suited for Law.SE?

Comment: Edited the question to better match site's topic. BTW I posted on SuperUser, they suggested to post here. Posted here you suggested to post on Law.se. Posted on Law.se they suggested to post here.

Comment: Very important point, the legality of carrying encrypting devices and refusing border inspection are **two completely separate issues**.  Nearly every handset uses full device encryption and customs can inspect the content of anything they want from you back pocket to encrypted files.

Comment: If I cross a border with an encrypted file custom can pretend to see it decrypted? That's what you're stating? So what if I forget home the decryption key of one file they want to inspect? Lifetime jail?

Comment: @Marco Both practice and your legal rights and duties will differ significantly from country to country, even within the EU. If you refuse to comply with a legal customs search, your best bet is probably 'only' to be refused entry. More likely, you will indeed be detained or even arrested. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: Nearly every iPhone and most Windows machines are fully encrypted and cross borders every day without issues and I'm not aware of any country that outright bans iPhones from coming in.  However, Customs can ask to inspect anything crossing it's border.  Opening your suitcase and unlocking the device/file are essentially the same thing.  If they want to inspect it, you have to either comply, turn around or surrender the item.

Comment: That’s how stupid mankind can be. I could upload encrypted files in the cloud and cross the borders with the plaintext keys. That’s probably what a criminal would do as they know the law better than lawyers. While an IT professional can’t cross borders bringing its customers sensitive informations without having to undisclose ‘em all? I should really ask a lawyer what I should do because accomplishing to such a customs search would violate almost every contract I have in place with my customers.

Comment: Note that the informatin you wish to protect is _sensitive_. "Sensible" means "behaving in a level-headed way."

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sorry for my bad English, thanks for helping me to improve it!

Comment: @Marco No problem -- it's a common mistake among speakers of Romance languages.

Comment: @Marco For clarity, you are probably way over thinking this.  Unless border Officers have a reason to inspect you, they don't.

Comment: @Johns-305 unfortunately I think that bringing a Ledger Nano S with me might probably be one of that good reasons! It’s a cryptocurrency hardware wallet where theoretically an unlimited amount of money could be “stored”. BTW, mine just holds a few thousands dollars, and leaving it home is not an option.

Comment: @Marco I still think you're overthinking this.  The Nano S is no more suspicious than an iPhone with Coinbase or other cc app.  Even then, it's not illegal in anyway because, regardless of its form, you must declare monetary instruments.  It doesn't matter if it's cash or Bitcoin.

Comment: @Johns-305 hate to use comments as a chat, but I can't refrain to ask: you mean that as I would say that I have one thousand euros in cash in my pocket I should also say that I have my Nano and the amount it contains?? That would be really awful -.-'

Comment: @Marco Why?  It no different.  If you cross, say the US, border with >$10,000 dollars, you have to declare it.  It can be cash, a check, and if pending legislation passes, BitCoin and other cc's.  People have this thought that BitCoin is somehow special...well..it's not, sorry.  It's just another currency, like Dollars, Euros, SkyMiles, etc.  The BitCoin in your Nano is no different than a check in your wallet.

Comment: Sorry @Johns-305 but when you cross the border with cash or the check, the money ARE WITH YOU. Cryptocurrencies are just on the blockchains, not on any hardware device. The “wallet” is the key. It’s like if I cross the border with the 2FA code generator for my bank account and they want to know how much money I have on that bank account. Exact same thing.

Comment: @Marco You're thinking too narrowly any may have missed the point about the pending legislation.  Yes, it's silly since you can trade BitCoin from multiple devices(mostly ;), but, unlike a bank account, there is no way to recover or confiscate BitCoin without the k/pw so the k/pw becomes the instrument.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A discussion about what rights you have or don't have isn't a discussion you want to have with a customs officer who barely speaks your language. It takes time and nerves for both you, them and anyone waiting in line behind you. And when you annoy them too much with being a smart-ass about the local search-and-seizure laws, they will see what they *can* legally do to inconvenience you as much as possible (and maybe even illegally if they know they can get away with it). When it turns out that your rights were indeed violated by the customs officers, then all you can do about it is complain afterwards. That might result in the customs officer getting into trouble, but that won't get you back your time and dignity.

It's really not worth it.

The best way to avoid that trouble is to:

1. encrypt any sensitive data
2. upload the encrypted data to a server
3. delete the data from your device
4. travel to your destination
5. show them the clean device at the border
6. download and decrypt the data

Comment: I definitely appreciate the practical suggestion about not challenging the customs officers. Though I still feel uncomfortable about all this. Searching my files because they’re crossing borders. While they might ever search a terrorist’s computer they’ll always find it clean, for sure! :@

Answer (score 7):

Some countries do have so-called Key Disclosure Laws that can make it a crime to refuse to provide decryption keys. But in most cases there would need to be a criminal investigation or a court order before this can be applied.

All of this varies widely by country, so I suggest you check out [Key disclosure law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_disclosure_law) on Wikipedia.

For customs/border checks in particular, they can, in theory, ask for pretty much anything they want; if you refuse, devices may be confiscated and/or you may be denied entry.

Possible duplicate: [Do I need to provide PIN or password for my digital accessories, when entering Canada?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/89741/do-i-need-to-provide-pin-or-password-for-my-digital-accessories-when-entering-c?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the effort in your reply. Also the Wikipedia resource was very appreciated. So the conclusion is that I shouldn’t cross borders with datas I don’t want to be forced to undisclose!